# Capybara fill_in isn't working

Tags: capybara

I'm working in Rails 4.2.1 and doing testing using Capybara 2.4. I have an issue with some input fields not getting filled in using the capybara fill_in method.

I'm not getting an ElementNotFound error, I'm getting this:

expected: "2018-01-10"
     got: ""

(compared using ==)

Here's the test code:
**Note: fill_in works for the email, password and program name fields but not for the primary_training_start, primary_comp_start and primary_comp_end.**

```
  it 'create program' do
    visit '/'
    fill_in 'Email', with: 'john@doe.com'
    fill_in 'Enter Your Password', with: 'test123'
    click_on 'Log In'
    fill_in 'Program Name', with: 'My Training'
    find('.exclusive').click
    click_on 'Next Step'
    all('.creator-wayfinder li')[1].click
    expect(page).to have_content('SET THE SCHEDULE')
    fill_in 'primary_training_start', with: '2018-01-10'
    fill_in 'primary_comp_start', with: '2018-02-10'
    fill_in 'primary_comp_end', with: '2018-03-10'
    expect(find_field('primary_training_start').value).to eq('2018-01-10')
    expect(find_field('primary_comp_start').value).to eq('2018-02-10')
    expect(find_field('primary_comp_end').value).to eq('2018-03-10')
    click_on 'Show Program Schedule'
  end
```

And here's the HTML for the primary_training_start field:

```
           <div>
            <mark>Start Training</mark>
            <span class="datepicker" date-format="M/d/yyyy" date-set="{{program.training_calendar_details.primary_training_start}}">
              <input required
              ng-model="program.training_calendar_details.primary_training_start"
              name="primary_training_start"
              type="text" tabbable tabindex="0" />
            </span>
            <errors for="primary_training_start" model="program.training_calendar_details.primary_training_start"></errors>
          </div>
```

I tried this: [Capybara won't fill in form fields (although it finds them)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884136/capybara-wont-fill-in-form-fields-although-it-finds-them) but didn't have any luck.

Comment: Are these fields being controlled by some sort of JS widget?  If so just sending keys directly to the element (which is what fill_in does) may be getting changed by the JS handlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try having an id for input

```
<input required
 ng-model="program.training_calendar_details.primary_training_start"
 name="program[training_calendar_details][primary_training_start]"
 id="primary_training_start"
 type="text" tabbable tabindex="0" />
```

fill_in use first parameter as id

Comment: 'fill_in's first parameter could be either (a) be the label for the input field (b) an input id (ie "id_name" and not "#id_name") or (c) the name attribute